# How do you repeat an image only vertically in android?

Tags: java, android, image

Is there a way to repeat an image only vertically in android? I've tried it like this:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/asphalt_texture"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true"/>
```

But it repeats both ways and I only want it repeated vertically, any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strangely enough, there does not seem to be a way to do this in XML. Through code, however, you can. The following methods:

[`BitmapDrawable.setTileModeX(Shader.TileMode mode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeX%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29)
[`BitmapDrawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode mode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#setTileModeY%28android.graphics.Shader.TileMode%29)

should do what you need. Simply pass in one of the [`Shader.TileMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Shader.TileMode.html) enumerations (`REPEAT`, `MIRROR`, `CLAMP`) for whichever axis (y-axis for vertical) you need the repeat effect on.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
BitmapDrawable draw = (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.draw);
draw.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. I did that then used image.setImageDrawable(draw); and it doesn't repeat.

Comment: Was your draw.xml drawable the same as posted above, minus the tileMode attribute?

Comment: It works if I use draw.setBackgroundDrawable(draw), and add both the setTileModeX and setTileModeY, but that defeats the purpose of just vertical.

Comment: `draw.setBackgroundDrawable(draw)`? Setting to itself? I'm assuming that's just a typo, but yeah, if that doesn't work, I don't have any other suggestions to add, unfortunately. :(

Comment: lol yeah that was a typo, okay I'll try to figure it out, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel it is straight forward:(This code will tile in Y and repeat in x)

In your onWindowFoucsChanged you call:

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Drawable d = getRepeatingBG(this, R.drawable.image_that_you_want_to_repeat);
        body_view.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

    }

private Drawable getRepeatingBG(Activity activity, int center)
    {   

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled=true;

        Bitmap center_bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), center, options);
        center_bmp.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
        center_bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(center_bmp, dm.widthPixels , center_bmp.getHeight(), true);

        BitmapDrawable center_drawable = new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(),center_bmp);
//change here setTileModeY to setTileModeX if you want to repear in X
        center_drawable.setTileModeY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

        return center_drawable;
    }
```